# Are questions about mathematics programs appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a family member who is contemplating participating in a [semester-long mathematics program](http://www.budapestsemesters.com/) as a "year abroad" and am looking for informed opinions on the quality of the program and how it is viewed by other mathematicians. Is Math.SE the appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: How do you propose to distinguish the informed opinions from the uninformed ones?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The usual ways: [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson?tab=reputation) and [observation](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson?tab=answers).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius As someone who has asked such a question here before, I can say it was useful to me but am still not sure it was topical (naturally I wouldn't vote to close though). Per distinguishing opinions: I would caution you against giving reputation too much weight in this regard. It does not accurately reflect mathematical ability or knowledge of the discipline. For example, I am one of the top 100 users here in terms of reputation but still a novice and anything I have to say on a mathematics program other than KU or UChicago would be pure speculation.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Yes, I see the limitations. There certainly wouldn't be a direct correspondence between reputation, fro example, and the validity of authority of information about a specific program; but it could still serve as a guide to something like "trustworthiness". And if no one has here has anything to say about the program at all, it does would *suggest* it is obscure.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius In light of what I just said, it may be a bad time to mention that I just clicked on your link and have in fact heard of that program.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Predictions have a way of being contradicted! And what have you heard?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Not much, but it was something graduate students at the University of Kansas used to go to. It was good enough that the department kept sending people at least, for what that's worth.